# Powersave governor VS Marshmallow Doze

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, battery-life, 5.1-lollipop, kernel

After searching on Google and XDA for an answer (which I didn't find), I decided to pose this as a question here.

So, I guess that the majority of us know about the so-called big difference between Android Marshmallow and its predecessors: the **Doze** feature. We do know that it manages wakelocks and the such in a clever way, apparently granting longer autonomy to a device. I had the occasion to test it on my device, and at least for me, it is true.

Now, due to some issues (including general unsatisfying changes implemented in Marshmallow, as well as random reboots), I decided to fall back to Lollipop. Still, even if I find it to be more reliable than Marshmallow (probably because of the fair long time destined to its development), I noticed the difference in my device's battery autonomy: despite it being in standby for the same amount of time, the battery discharges faster than it did when I used Marshmallow.

So, here's my question: is it possible, with a **powersave** governor in a **Lollipop** Android, to achieve the same, if not least, battery consumption that one could notice with **Doze** in a **Marshmallow** Android?

***I prefer not to take advantage of Play Store apps, since mine is a question whose solution has not to be found with any auxiliary third-party software, and please support your answer with actual facts or appropriate research.***

Comment: Doze is different from *powersave* in that it utilizes the *deep sleep* feature of the kernel, resulting in less power consumption than using *powersave* but being active all the time. *powersave* forces the CPU to work at it's lowest speed possible which is not the most efficient one. Thus using *doze* you will experience less battery consumption (note to myself: post a more elaborate answer).

Comment: *deep sleep* uses so little power because it does not run the CPU at any speed (literally 0MHz). It's a hardware feature that works together with the RTC (real time clock) to wake the CPU at a given time but keep it sleeping the rest of the time.

Comment: @GiantTree So, in fact, the frequency of a CPU in deep sleep (e.g. Doze) is always less than the frequency of a CPU governed by a powersave governor. Did I get it?

Comment: Yes. In fact the CPU is not even running while in deep sleep. That's why there are people complaining about wake locks that are preventing deep sleep. Those are now ignored with doze if they are only running in the background (ie. not playing music for example)

Comment: @GiantTree Given your explanation, if I would emulate the features of Marshmallow's Doze on a Lollipop, I would necessarily need a third-party app, correct?

Comment: You are correct (the fact that you could write your own code doesn't count, as that again would result in an app ;) Best known candidates for this purpose are Greenify and the Amplify XPosed module.

Comment: @Izzy Thanks for the two recommendations (even if we're going a little bit off-topic from the AE guidelines :P). I might try them, and see which one yields the best results. Oh, and GiantTree might want to add his answer: the facts he pointed out greatly answer my question.

Comment: @Izzy Just as a footnote, I would like to inform that I'm testing the "Doze" app made by "YirgaLab", and it's yielding pretty positive results, so far.

Comment: Additional candidates, as usual, on my site: [Battery Savers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_batterysaver) :)